# Fill DataTable with data from ComboBox.DataSource in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, combobox, datasource

I need to get value from ComboBox.DataSource in a winforms. There are few columns inside and one of them is named "Seq". I need to get value of "Seq" column like this:

```
seq1 = dataTable1.Rows[0]["Seq"];
```

Combobox is in DataGridView. How can I fill dataTable1 from ComboBox.DataSource, something like that?:

```
DataTable dataTable1=comboBox.DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - that is easy:

```
DataTable dataTable1 = (DataTable) comboBox.DataSource;
```